# $rownum = mysqli_num_rows($result); return 0 but must return 1

Tags: php, authentication

I have a row in my table and I wrote this code for my login page. Unfortunately, it is working on user's login page but not on the admin login page.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")) {
        $rownum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rownum == 1){
             $_SESSION['print_admin'] = 'ok';
             header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
             die();
        } else {
             echo "password is wrong";
        }
    }
```

The `$rownum` returns 0 but the username and password exist as a row on the table

Comment: try to change that to `$rownum > 1`

Comment: echo your query and run into phpmyadmin check what it return

Comment: i do that and it can't find row in phpmyadmin too! but it is exist on table and i'm sure my values are true...

Comment: Well, then obviously there's some difference in your actual data in your database and what you expect. Without any details we can't help you very much here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
echo $sql; //copy and test using phpmyadmin :D

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {

  $rownum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($rownum == 1){
      $_SESSION['print_admin'] = 'ok';
      header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
      die();
  }
  else {
      echo "password is wrong";
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess your sql is: SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' . Problem is Single-quoted

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
   if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")) {


     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
     $_SESSION['print_admin'] = 'ok';
     header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
     die();
   }
    else {
            echo "password is wrong";
   }
}
```